# How to keep ViewHolder's width after view was recycled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` as horizontal list to show my images.

If I scroll to the fifth picture, the first two or three are recycled and ViewHolder loses its width. If I scroll back to the first image, the images are loaded again and that leads to jumps while scrolling.

Here is `R.layout.fragment_details_view_img_item`

```
<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/details_view_img_item"
  android:background="@color/red"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ImageView>
```

My ViewHolder and Adapter:

```
private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(ImageView imgV){
        super(imgV);
        img = imgV;
    }
}

private class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    [...]

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_details_view_img_item, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(listener);

        logDebug("onCreateViewHolder");

        return new ViewHolder((ImageView) v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        logDebug("onBindViewHolder");

        ImageItem item = data.get(i);

        if (item != null) {

            ImageView imgView = viewHolder.img;
            imgView.setTag(item);

            String imgurl = ImageUtil.imgUrlForAvailableHeightInPX(item, parentHeight);

            ImageLoader.instance().loadASYNC(imgurl, imgView);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        logDebug("onViewRecycled: " + holder.img.getTag());
    }

}
```

So how can I keep ViewHolder's width?

Answer (score 0):

Before I start to approach this problem, one thing needs to be clear. The `ViewHolder` doesn't have any width, the `ImageView` it "holds" does have width, and that's what you're trying to control.

Now, considering this, your issue is (after making certain assumptions from looking at your code) that you need to know the width of a certain image when it is at a certain given height and while maintaining aspect ratio - before it arrives from the server.

This is a tricky one.

One option would be to preload all your images. This, however, is very costly with memory and could lead to memory crashes.

A better option would be to load all the images' details, without actually downloading the images' pixels. Then, you'll need to remember the aspect ratio of all the images in some cache, and set the dimension of the image you're loading prior to actually downloading the image contents.

To download an image's dimensions without downloading the image itself, you should use something like this:

```
public float getImageAspectRatio(InputStream inputStreamFromServer)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStreamFromServer, null, decodeOptions);

    final float imageDesiredWidth = decodeOptions.outWidth;
    final float imageDesiredHeight = decodeOptions.outHeight;

    return imageDesiredWidth / imageDesiredHeight;
}
```

Once you have this method, you'll need to preload all your images using this function:

```
private float[] mAspectRatios;
public void decodeAllAspectRatios(List<String> imageUrls)
{
    mAspectRatios = new float[imageUrls.size()];
    InputStream inputStream;
    int index = 0;

    for (String url : imageUrls) 
    {
        // Get the input stream from the image url using whatever method you use.

        mAspectRatios[index] = getImageAspectRatio(inputStream);
        index++;  
    } 
}
```

**Important:** Your `RecyclerView` should not begin working until this method finished working.

Once you have preloaded all your aspect ratios, we go back to your ViewHolder:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        logDebug("onBindViewHolder");

        ImageItem item = data.get(i);

        if (item != null) {

            ImageView imgView = viewHolder.img;

            // set the layout params of the image, making it fit the correct size prior to loading the bitmap.
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(parentHeight * mAspectRatios[i], parentHeight));
            imgView.setTag(item);

            String imgurl = ImageUtil.imgUrlForAvailableHeightInPX(item, parentHeight);

            ImageLoader.instance().loadASYNC(imgurl, imgView);

        }
    }
```

So long as you want your `RecyclerView` to display varying width images depending on their aspect ratio, I believe this is your best option.

Comment: the width of a image after `onViewRecycled` is still the same, it never changes. So there is no need to `setLayoutParams` :(